# Cannot debug getVecs, getCoupls, and findCCvec functions in Python script with certain Mus_df values

Tags: python-3.x, chemistry

I have the following code that gets some input files and calculates some values. The issue is, the code is working for `Mus_df` values `1,2,3,4,6,12` but not `5,7,8,9,10,11`. The error indicates that `CCvecs` is None-type. Can you help me?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
import itertools
from math import sqrt, pi, sin, cos, asin, acos, exp
import pandas as pd
cmap1 = plt.get_cmap('tab10')

ang2au = 1.8897259886
eV2au = 3.6749322175655e-2
debye2au = 0.393456   

def readParams(NpAndMol_xyz_path, Mol_xyz_path, Np_Mu_path, Nmol, t=0.0):
    # read NP+pyr and pyr XYZ into pd df
    # read TDMs of Ag174 NP system, select electronic states? based on cutoff for f..???
    NpAndMol_xyz_tmp = pd.read_csv(
        NpAndMol_xyz_path, sep='\s+', header=None, skiprows=2)
    Mol_xyz_df = pd.read_csv(Mol_xyz_path, sep='\s+', header=None, skiprows=2)
    Mus_tmp_df = pd.read_csv(Np_Mu_path, sep='\s+', header=None,
                             skiprows=2, names=['no', 'E', 'f', 'x', 'y', 'z'])

    # parse NpAndMol_xyz
    NpAndMol_xyz_df = NpAndMol_xyz_tmp.drop(
        NpAndMol_xyz_tmp[NpAndMol_xyz_tmp[0] == 'Ag'].index)
    NP_xyz = NpAndMol_xyz_tmp[NpAndMol_xyz_tmp[0] == 'Ag'].to_numpy()
    MolsOnNP_xyz = np.array_split(NpAndMol_xyz_df, Nmol)

    # get only xyz of TDMs
    # threshold t for oscillator strength f optional
    Mus_tmp_dfRed = Mus_tmp_df.loc[(Mus_tmp_df['f'] >= t)]
    Mus_df = Mus_tmp_dfRed.drop(Mus_tmp_dfRed.columns[[1, 2]], axis=1)
    elStateEs = Mus_tmp_dfRed['E'].tolist()

    return NP_xyz, MolsOnNP_xyz, Mol_xyz_df, Mus_df, elStateEs


def getVecs(MolsOnNP_xyz, Mol_xyz_df):
    Nmol = len(MolsOnNP_xyz)
    CMOnNPvecs = []
    NNvecs = []
    RotMats = []
    CCvecs = []

    # get CoM of pyr molecules, CM(NP)=(0,0,0)
    Mol_xyzMat = Mol_xyz_df.drop(Mol_xyz_df.columns[[0]], axis=1).to_numpy()
    NNOrig = Mol_xyzMat[1, :] - Mol_xyzMat[3, :]

    #testvecOrig = Mol_xyzMat[2, :] - Mol_xyzMat[5, :]
    for i in range(Nmol):
        MolOnNP_xyz = MolsOnNP_xyz[i]
        MolOnNP_xyzMat = MolsOnNP_xyz[i].drop(
            MolOnNP_xyz.columns[[0]], axis=1).to_numpy()

        # compute NN vector
        NsXYZ = MolOnNP_xyz[MolOnNP_xyz[0] == 'N']
        NsXYZ_mat = NsXYZ.drop(NsXYZ.columns[[0]], axis=1).to_numpy()
        NNOnNPvec = NsXYZ_mat[0, :] - NsXYZ_mat[1, :]

        NNOnNPvec_normal = NNOnNPvec * 1/np.linalg.norm(NNOnNPvec)
        CMOnNPvecTmp = (MolOnNP_xyzMat[2, :] + MolOnNP_xyzMat[5, :])*0.5

        # compute CC vec parallel to TDM vector
        # CCvec = MolOnNP_xyzMat[3, :] - MolOnNP_xyzMat[1, :]
        CCvec = findCCVec(MolOnNP_xyz,NNOnNPvec)
        # print(np.linalg.norm(CCvec))
        CCvecs.append(CCvec)
        #print(len(CCvecs))
        NNvecs.append(NNOnNPvec)
        CMOnNPvecs.append(CMOnNPvecTmp)

    return CCvecs, CMOnNPvecs, NNvecs


def alignAntiParallelVec(u, v):
    if np.dot(u, v) < 0:
        print('antiparallel')
        return -v
    elif np.dot(u, v) > 0:
        print('parallel')
        return v
    elif np.dot(u, v) == 0:
        print('vectors are orthogonal')
        return v


def getCoupls(CCvecs, CMOnNPvecs, Mus_df, mydist=None, printOut=False, unit='au', multiplier=1.0):
    #muMolBf = np.array([0.00000, 0.78457, 0.0000])
    muMolBf = np.array([0.00000, -0.8915, 0.0000])
    muMolBfAbs = np.linalg.norm(muMolBf)
    musNP = Mus_df[['x', 'y', 'z']].to_numpy()

    print('take mu vectors from input:')
    print('\n###Cluster mu (modulus) in au###')
    print([np.linalg.norm(v) for v in musNP])
    print('\n###Molecule mu (modulus) in au###')
    print(muMolBfAbs)

    elStateInds = Mus_df['no'].to_list()
    Nmol = len(CCvecs)
    print(Nmol)

    Nel = len(Mus_df.index)
    gcoupls = np.zeros((Nmol, Nel))

    uvec_out = []

    for i in range(Nmol):
        uvec = 1/np.linalg.norm(CMOnNPvecs[i]*ang2au) * CMOnNPvecs[i]*ang2au
        print(CCvecs[i])
        muMolVec = CCvecs[i]*ang2au
        #muMolVec = alignAntiParallelVec(uvec, CCvecs[i])
        muMolSf = muMolBfAbs/np.linalg.norm(muMolVec) * muMolVec

        # uvec_out.append(muMolVec)

        if mydist == None:
            dist = np.linalg.norm(CMOnNPvecs[i])
            dist_au = dist*ang2au
            print('###Calculate dip-dip distance from coordinate file###')
            print('dist = {} å = {} au'.format(dist, dist_au))
        else:
            print('###Use custom dist###')
            dist = mydist
            dist_au = dist*ang2au

        for j in range(len(musNP)):
            gcoupls[i, j] = 1/dist_au**3 * (np.dot(musNP[j], muMolSf) -
                                            3*np.dot(musNP[j], uvec)*np.dot(muMolSf, uvec))
            # g_ij matrix, i=mol index, j=el state index

    if printOut:
        print('\n\n###coupling matrix g_ij; i=mol, j=el state###')
        for i in range(Nmol):
            for j in range(Nel):
                if unit == 'ev':
                    print('g_{}_{} = {:.5f}, ev'.format(
                        i+1, j+1, gcoupls[i, j]/eV2au*multiplier))
                elif unit == 'au':
                    print('g_{}_{} = {:.5f}'.format(
                        i+1, j+1, gcoupls[i, j]*multiplier))
                else:
                    print('unknown unit!')
        print('\n###metal mus###')
        for i in range(Nel):
            # read and print maximum TDM component
            muInd = np.argmax(np.abs(musNP[i]))
            print("mu_1_{} = {:.4f}".format(i+1, musNP[i][muInd]))
    return gcoupls


def findCCVec(molXYZ_df,NNvec):
    CsXYZ = molXYZ_df[molXYZ_df[0] == 'C']
    
    CsXYZ_Mat = CsXYZ.drop(CsXYZ.columns[[0]], axis=1).to_numpy()
    Nmols = len(CsXYZ_Mat[:])
    Inds = range(Nmols)
    iters = itertools.combinations(Inds,2)

    failCount = 0

    for iter in iters:
        CCtestVec = CsXYZ_Mat[iter[0]] -  CsXYZ_Mat[iter[1]] 
        projCCNN = CCtestVec.dot(NNvec)
        if np.abs(projCCNN) <= 1e-7:
            return CCtestVec
        else:
            failCount += 1
    
    if failCount == Nmols:
        print("No suitable CC axis found")
        return None

def printEs(elist, shift=0.0):
    print("omega_0 = 0.0000, ev")
    for i, e in enumerate(elist):
        print("omega_{} = {:.4f}, ev".format(i+2, e+shift))


def printCouplOp(MolDofs, MolTags, NElStates, elDof):
    for molTag, molDof in zip(MolTags, MolDofs):
        for j in range(NElStates):
            print("g_{}_{}        |{}  F |{}  S1&{}".format(
                molTag, j+1, molDof, elDof, j+2))
    for j in range(int(NElStates/2)):
        print("omega_1     |{} S{}&{}".format(elDof, 2*j+2, 2*j+2))
        print("omega_2     |{} S{}&{}".format(elDof, 2*j+3, 2*j+3))
    for j in range(int(NElStates/2)):
        print("omega_1     |{} S{}&{}".format(elDof, 2*j+2, 2*j+2))
        print("omega_2     |{} S{}&{}".format(elDof, 2*j+3, 2*j+3))

        
def visVecs(cms, vecs, l=0.1, angle=0, pts = None, plotPts = False):
    ax = plt.figure().add_subplot(projection='3d')
    ax.view_init(30, angle)
    for i in range(len(cms)):
        ax.scatter(cms[i,0].tolist(),cms[i,1].tolist(),cms[i,2].tolist(),color=cmap1(i),marker='*',s=50)
    ax.quiver(cms[:,0],cms[:,1], cms[:,2], vecs[:,0], vecs[:,1], vecs[:,2], length=l, normalize=True, color='black')
    if plotPts:
        #print(pts[:,1])
        #print(pts[:,2])
        #print(pts[:,3])
        #ax.scatter(pts[:,1],pts[:,2],pts[:,3])
        ax.scatter(pts[:,1].tolist(),pts[:,2].tolist(),pts[:,3].tolist())
    plt.show()

#visVecs(np.array(CMOnNPvecs), np.array(CCvecs), l=1, angle=40)
Np_xyz , MolsOnNP_xyz, Mol_xyz_df, Mus_df, elStateEs = readParams(
    'Ag147-py12.xyz', 'Pyr_xyz.dat', 'Ag147_mu_sym_e1u_xy.dat',8 , t=0.000)

CCvecs, CMOnNPvecs, NNvecs = getVecs(MolsOnNP_xyz, Mol_xyz_df)

coupls = getCoupls(CCvecs, CMOnNPvecs, Mus_df, mydist = None , printOut = True, unit = 'ev', multiplier=1.0)
```

The `Mus_df` value is prompted in this line `Np_xyz , MolsOnNP_xyz, Mol_xyz_df, Mus_df, elStateEs = readParams( 'Ag147-py12.xyz', 'Pyr_xyz.dat', 'Ag147_mu_sym_e1u_xy.dat',8 , t=0.000)`, which is set to be `8` in this case.

I tried debugging `getVecs`, `getCoupls`, `findCCvec` functions but had no luck. Can you please help me?

Comment: You should share the exact error message and the entire stack trace.